# Laravel could not find driver using laragon

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laragon

Am working on a project using laravel on my local machine with [laragon](https://laragon.org/) and trying to build this project using TDD and when I tried to run a test it gives me an error.

`Tests\Feature\ProjectsTest::a_user_can_create_a_project
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)`

I already configured my settings under MENU -> PHP -> Extensions and enabled sqlite, also  tried creating `database.sqlite` on my **app/database/** folder but still get the same error.

Am using Laravel 5.8 and am on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Enable in Laragon PHP->Extensions: pdo_sqlite, and optional sqlite3.